# Android INSTALL_FAILED_INSUFFICIENT_STORAGE error

Tags: android, debugging, installation, adb, space

I have looked through at least a dozen or so posts on this website but yet no one has been able to figure this problem out. I keep getting the INSTALL_FAILED_INSUFFICIENT_STORAGE error when trying to test an app on a real device. Restarting the device and/or uninstalling then reinstalling the app works FOR ONLY ONE TEST RUN. After that, the error pops right back up. I'm not looking for a solution for an emulated device, and my device has 4.27GB free space so that's not an issue either. I just need a fix for this problem without having to keep restarting the device/uninstalling the app.

Also, I've tried the whole `android:installLocation="preferExternal"` method in the manifest and that does not work.

EDIT: Here is my manifest:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.*****.*****"
    android:installLocation="preferExternal"
    android:versionCode="2"
    android:versionName="1.0.1" >
```

The rest of my manifest is just the `<uses-sdk>` tag and `<activity>` tags. Sorry for the poorly formatted code, for some reason tabbing within a text box doesn't work on this website for me.

EDIT: All I'm asking for (as well as anyone else who has asked this question on this site) is a solution FOR ACTUAL DEVICES that have PLENTY OF FREE SPACE and NO SD CARD SLOT. It seems no one on this site has a solution for what I feel is the most common scenario for this problem.

Comment: put your menifest config file first.

Comment: I've updated my post with the manifest.

Comment: check first by removing 'android:installLocation="preferExternal"' line and see what is happening. what is 4.27 GB? internal or external?

Comment: I've removed 'android:installLocation' and it still gives the error. And it's 4.27GB internal, there's no SD card slot.

Comment: then try with other device and simulator as well and check result.

Comment: It's only been happening with my Nexus 7 (grouper). My phone devices and none of the emulators bring up this error.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Fixed it with simple restarting of my Android mobile device ('LG L70')

Windows Command line:

```
d:\>adb -s LGL70 install myapp.apk
[100%] /data/local/tmp/myapp.apk
        pkg: /data/local/tmp/myapp.apk
Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_INSUFFICIENT_STORAGE]
```

After restart the device:

```
d:\>adb -s LGL70 install myapp.apk
[100%] /data/local/tmp/myapp.apk
        pkg: /data/local/tmp/myapp.apk
Success
```